# Batch File to move files to folders base on part of their name

Tags: batch-file

I am looking for one solution, which will help me to move files to folders with similar name.

I have filenames like `TEST1_2018P2.xlsx`, `TEST2_2018P2.xslx`, etc.

And I have folders with names `TEST1_City1`, `TEST2 City2`...

What I need is to move file `TEST1_2018P2.xlsx` to folder `TEST1_City1`, `TEST2_2018P2.xslx` to `TEST2 City2` and so on.

How can I do that?

Here's my latest code, which is also not working.

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=my_folder"
SET "destdir=my_folder"
FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN ( 'dir /b /a-d "%sourcedir%\*.xlsx" ' ) DO (
    FOR /f "tokens=1delims=" %%b IN ("%%a") DO (
        FOR /f "delims=" %%d IN ( 'dir /b /ad "%destdir%\*%%b*" ' ) DO (
            ECHO(MOVE "%%a" "%destdir%\%%d\"
        )
    )
)
GOTO :EOF
```

Comment: can you share what you have tried?

Comment: Hi double-beep, I have tried your code. Unfortunately it is not working properly.  Code moved files to newly created folders TEST1_CityTEST and other following folders, but didn´t move files to "original" folders.

Comment: @Greg
I have tried this code meantime and it is not working.

`@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=my_folder"
SET "destdir=my_folder"
FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN (
'dir /b /a-d "%sourcedir%\*.xlsx" '
) DO (
FOR /f "tokens=1delims=" %%b IN ("%%a") DO (
FOR /f "delims=" %%d IN (
'dir /b /ad "%destdir%\*%%b*" '
) DO (
ECHO(MOVE "%%a" "%destdir%\%%d\"
)
)
)

GOTO :EOF`

Comment: @BranislavŽupančič whoops! My bad! I made several tests in cmd and something went wrong. I have fixed the error, can you recheck?

Comment: @double-beep now it is working correctly! To be honest solution of Compo is more suitable for  me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure of your exact task, so this relatively basic example should move any `.xlsx` file to the first existing directory whose name matches the portion of the filename up to the underscore, plus a space.

Adjust the values on lines `2` and `3` to match your actual directory specs, *(without trailing backslashes)*.

```bat
@Echo Off
Set "SourceDir=my_folder"
Set "DestDir=my_folder"
For /F Delims^=^ EOL^= %%A In ('Dir /B/A-D-L "%SourceDir%\*_*.xlsx" 2^>Nul'
) Do Call :Sub "%%A"
GoTo :EOF

:Sub
Set "DirName=%~1"
Set "DirName=%DirName:_="&:"%"
For /F Delims^=^ EOL^= %%A In ('Dir /B/AD-L "%DestDir%\%DirName% *" 2^>Nul'
) Do If Exist "%SourceDir%%~1" Move /Y "%SourceDir%\%~1" "%DestDir%\%%A" 2>Nul
Exit /B
```

*It was not designed to be the most efficient method of performing the task!*

*Please also note that your existing directory names did not have a clear pattern so this was written for `TEST1 City1` `TEST2 City2` etc.
If they are all underscores, e.g. `TEST1_City1` `TEST2_City2` etc. then change `"%DestDir%\%DirName% *"` on line `11` to `"%DestDir%\%DirName%_*"`.*
*If the directories can be either of them, and you are sure that no two directories will begin with the string `TEST1`, `TEST2` etc., (which would limit you to only numbers 0..9 in this case), you could probably use `"%DestDir%\%DirName%?*"` on line `11` as an alternative.*

Comment: This code works for my task properly without any problems.

Comment: For some reason, I had to do some adjustements to the directory paths in order for it to work. Would you know why? My script is like this:

Do If Exist "%SourceDir%\%~1" Move /Y "%SourceDir%\%~1" "%DestDir%\%%A" 2>Nul

Comment: @Kenneth, you're absolutely correct, that was my error, now updated accordingly in my answer, along with additional information in the footnote.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that actual text of `TEST1` **doesn't contain** any `_` characters, you can use:

```bat
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

cd /d "your_folder"
for /F "delims= eol=" %%A IN ('dir /B /A-D "TEST*_2018P2.xlsx"') do (
    for /F "tokens=1 delims=_" %%B IN ("%%A") do (
        rem Define some important variables:
        set "token_1=%%B"
        set "num_test=!token_1:~-1!"
        set "foldername=!token_1!_City!num_test!"
        md "!foldername!\" >nul 2>&1
        move "%%~fA" "!foldername!\"
    )
)
```

Let me explain my code:

- The first `for /F` loop is used to find all the files you want (`TEST*_2018P2.xlsx`) **excluding all directories (`/A-D`)** and headers. `delims=` and `eol=` options are used: loop through the whole line without skipping lines starting with `;`.
- The second `for /F` loop is used to get the first token of the output of the first loop (`IN ("%%A")`).

  - The first token is set to `token_1` variable and then substract the last number/letter from it setting it to the `num_test` variable.
  - A foldername is set because it is used two time, it is really hard to understand this code without setting it in a variable. It is actually set by `token_1` variable (`TESTn`), `_City` and `n` (number).
  - A folder is created with that name. Both STDIN and STDERR are redirected to `nul`. This happens not to have many processed `if exist` statement. The current file (`%%~fA`; full path) is moved to this folder.

Remember to replace `"your_folder"` with your actual folder!